# Executing muliple sql statements with Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

So it turns out Codeigniter struggles to execute more than 1 SQL statement at a time.

On way round this is to use the `trans_start` and `trans_complete` functions, however, this does not work for creating temp tables.

```
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->query( 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1;');
    $this->db->query( 'SELECT * FROM banner_data WHERE id = '.$id.';');
    $this->db->query( 'UPDATE tmptable_1 SET id = NULL;');
    $this->db->query( 'INSERT INTO banner_data SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;');
    $this->db->query( 'DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;');
    $this->db->trans_complete();
```

The above code generates the following error:

```
A table must have at least 1 column

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1;

Filename: models/Banners_generator_model.php
```

Is there a way to execute a whole block of SQL in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way around this:

```
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->query( 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM banner_data WHERE id = '.$id.';');
    $this->db->query( 'UPDATE tmptable_1 SET id = NULL;');
    $this->db->query( 'INSERT INTO banner_data SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;');
    $this->db->query( 'DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;');
    $this->db->trans_complete();
```

By merging the original first two lines, the database builds the table columns based on the structure of the table you are copying from.

Comment: But my answer is the better answer (IMHO). I've tested it fully and it works.

Answer (score 2):

The Error Simply point you.

> A **table** must have **at least 1 column**

So create Query should be like this. (Give all the table column names which you will store data )

***SQL CREATE TABLE Syntax***

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
    column_name1 data_type(size),
    column_name2 data_type(size),
    column_name3 data_type(size),
    ....
);
```

***Example***

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but that would require a very large sql statement because the table has many fields.

Comment: No harm its only execute one time

Comment: Yes true - but I like my code to be a minimal as possible.